# Delete an image by clicking on a button

Tags: css, reactjs, image, button

I want to delete one image by clicking on a button.

```
<img alt="image" src="https://image.png"/>
            <button onClick={() => removeImage}>X</button>
```

Comment: What do you mean delete?

Are you deleting by removing the image from the page/dom
Are you deleting by deleting that particular image from the database or image source?

Comment: I am deleting by removing the image from the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make the rendering of the image conditional (see [Conditional Rendering](https://reactpatterns.com/#conditional-rendering)) by using a state `renderImage`. If `renderImage` is `true` the image is rendered (= present on the page), if not, it's not rendered (= not present on the page).

```js
function App() {
  const [renderImage, setRenderImage] = React.useState(true);

  function removeImage() {
    setRenderImage(false);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {renderImage && (
        <img alt="image" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
      )}
      <button onClick={() => removeImage()}>X</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```